# iOS - how to put a custom pop-up before the APNS & enable location pop-ups

Tags: ios, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

I want to put a pop-up screen on my app before the iOS "Allow push notifications" and "Allow location updates" pop-up screens that show up. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply show your custom UI first then after that is complete call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`

Comment: ah ok. And how about the location pop-up?

Comment: Same thing with enabling location updates. Delay the call till your ui is done